# XALAN register Extension Function like in SAXON

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, xalan

i want to transform a XML by XSLT with XALAN. Now i want to use a extension-function, this function have to be added in JAVA source like in SAXON:

Method:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Configuration c = ((net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl) tFactory).getConfiguration();
c.registerExtensionFunction(new FooExtension());
```

FooExtension:

```
public class FooExtension extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8143237239412146617L;

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new SequenceType[] { SequenceType.EMPTY_SEQUENCE };
    }

    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName("ns", "http://namespace", "generate-guid");
    }
}
```

But how does it works in XALAN (?FunctionTable?, ?FunctionResolver?, ?URIResolver?) , i have to do it by source, i'm not allowed to add class in XSLT.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When registering the function in your java code, you still would have to declare the namespace in your stylesheet, don't you? In that case I don't think there is much conceptual difference between doing

```
xmlns:ns="http://namespace"
```

Or

```
xmlns:ns="xalan://package.classname"
```

The implementation just needs to contain a static function, further examples can be found at http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#ex-java-namespace and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xalanextensions.html

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not allowed to add the classname in xslt with xmlns. (Already written in the question)

Answer (score 0):

There's some excellent documentation on this matter from the Xalan project here: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html