# (Limited) Java extension function support in XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I've [long made do with the default XML libraries provided by Java](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2009/01/xml-and-xslt-tips-and-tricks-for-java.html) (Xerces2-J and Xalan-J) - occasionally and directly using the latest versions of those libraries when needed.  It appears I'm running up against some of the limits of these libraries - especially [with Xalan-J that is really no longer being maintained](http://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/apache-may-archive-xalan/) and [without a release for almost 6 years](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/readme.html)...

I need to provide some custom functions to pull information from external services when called, so they must be implemented in Java.  (i.e. I can't implement them within the XSLT itself, as either XSLT or JavaScript functions, etc.)  I've done this before using [Xalan-Java Extensions](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html).  However, providing this seems to be either allow-all or nothing:

- http://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/200911/msg00198.html
- http://marc.info/?l=xalan-j-users&m=123750821029013
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-1850

I need to be able to provide access to a Java extension - but without allowing any arbitrary calls out to Java (think of an embedded call to `System.exit()`, for example), and ideally, without the XSLT authors even needing to know that it is a Java function (by use of `xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"`, for example).  Ideally, I'd also be able to keep `TransformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);`.

I can do (almost) exactly what I'm looking for using `XPath.setXPathFunctionResolver`, but this only works for direct XPath calls - and I've not found a way to set a custom XPath for use in XSLT by Xalan.  (It also requires the `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` to not be set on the `XPathFactory`, though I might be able to get away with having it set only on the `TransformerFactory` - ignoring that if set on the TransformerFactory, the TransformerFactory also automatically sets the same flag on the XPathFactory that is uses.)

So I decided to give Saxon (Saxon-HE 9.5.1-1) a try - and am immediately noticing 2 issues:

1. When just using XPath directly, `XPath.setXPathFunctionResolver` does not seem to have any affect under Saxon.  The `set` call completes without issue, but `resolveFunction` on the passed-in `XPathFunctionResolver` is never even called under Saxon.  (It simply "just works" under Xalan.)  Is there some additional configuration necessary for Saxon - or is this maybe a limitation of the HE version?
2. <strike>I've looked at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-simple-J - which [per the author](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.saxon.help/12101), is provided for even under the HE version.  It also looks to be exactly what I need - however (like with `XPathFunctionResolver` under Xalan), I can't see how to wire this into XSLT processing.</strike>  (This is answered by the [XALAN register Extension Function like in SAXON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192412/xalan-register-extension-function-like-in-saxon) in the question itself.)

Comment: The JAXP XPath API, including the XPath.setXPathFunctionResolver call, is supported in Saxon-HE. If it's not working then we need to see more precisely exactly what you are doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using non-core EXSLT date functions with Xalan Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081400/using-non-core-exslt-date-functions-with-xalan-java)